# How to replace a list in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, indexing, enumerate

I have a file which contains my passwords like this:

---

```
Service: x
Username: y
Password: z
```

---

I want to write a method which deletes one of these password sections. The idea is, that I can search for a service and the section it gets deleted. So far the code works (I can tell because if you insert `print(section)` where I wrote delete section it works just fine), I just don't know how to delete something from the file.

```
fileee = '/home/manos/Documents/python_testing/resources_py/pw.txt'

def delete_password():
    file = open(fileee).read().splitlines()
    search = input("\nEnter Service you want to delete: ")
    if search == "":
        print("\nSearch can't be blank!")
        delete_password()
    elif search == "cancel":
        startup()
    else:
        pass
    found = False
    for index, line in enumerate(file):
        if 'Service: ' in line and search in line:
            password_section = file[index-1:index+3]
            # delete password_section
            found = True
    if not found:
        print("\nPassword for " + search + " was not found.")
        delete_password()
```

Comment: The simplest way is to re-write the file, writing everything except the part you want to delete.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Clearly you know how to read a file; do you know how to write a file? You already wrote code that figures out the part you want to delete. Can you write code that figures out what's *not* the part you want to delete? Should be pretty straightforward. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a line from the file is the same as re-writing the file minus that matching line.

```py
#read entire file
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

#delete 21st line
del lines[20]

#write back the file without the line you want to remove
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f:
  f.writelines(lines)
```